# How to get list of processes from N days ago from ps output

Tags: linux, date, kill, ps

How to get list of dates from an output of `ps` command to only show those processes beyond 30 days?

My goal is to kill these processes. I can easily do this by `killall` command.

E.g. `killall -u user --older-than 1M`

But we have an outdated version of that command to which `--older-than` is not available so I'm force to find another way.

One thing I'm thinking is to pass the list of processes to kill command but I couldn't figure it out how to only get the processes that are 30 days old and beyond.

If there's something like this:

```
ps --no-header -u username --sort=start_time -o user,pid,lstart | #get all processes beyond 30 days old | while read -r pid; do kill $pid; done
```

Edit: We're using procps version 3.2.8

Answer (score 2):

With relatively recent versions of procps, you can use `etimes` as the elapsed time as a number of seconds:

```
ps -Ao etimes= -o pid= |
  awk -v n=30 '$1 >= n*86400 {print $2}' |
  xargs -r kill
```

(here assuming GNU `xargs` for its `-r` option)

Or:

```
ps -Ao etimes= -o pid= |
  awk -v n=30 '$1 >= n*86400 {print "kill", $2}' |
  sh
```

With older versions, you can revert to `etime`:

```
LC_ALL=C ps -Ao etime= -o pid= |
  awk -v n=30 '$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+-/ && 0+$1 >= n {print "kill", $2}' |
  sh
```

(that syntax is POSIX and should work on all POSIX compliant systems).

Comment: `ps -Ao etimes= -o pid=` doesn't work. Throws error `ERROR: Unknown user-defined format specifier "etimes"`

Comment: @WashichawbachaW, yes like I said, you need a relatively recent version of procps (where your version of `ps` seems to be coming from) and I gave an alternative for older versions